# get multiple SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp

I have a table with 2 interesting entries:

**VALUE** with integer entries and **dtStart** with timestamp (date and time)

My actual query is:

```
SELECT SUM(value) as Sum
  FROM [DB].[table] 
  WHERE AND dtStart BETWEEN '20130401 00:00:00.000' 
    AND '20130402 00:00:00.000'
```

Thats a bit disappointing, because i need a query that gives me the solution for a day, but i need this for every day in a whole month. Now i'm editing the time field for every day.
Whats the solution to get multiple queries (1 per day) for every day in on query?

per example:

- day sum
- 1   2301
- 2   2905
- 3   1700
- ... ...

Comment: Which database are you using? Does `dtStart` also record the time or is it just a date?

Comment: MS SQL-Server and as i already wrote the record includes date and time

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    SUM(valueAns) AS totalval,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY dtStart)) AS day,
  dtStart
FROM
    a group by CONVERT(DATE, dtStart)
```

see the sql [demo for you answer](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34abb/5)

Comment: This will works only for `mysql`. Question tagged by `sql-server`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `GROUP BY` the day, as `dtStart` has times in then these can be 'removed' by converting it to a `DATE`

```
SELECT DATEPART(DD, CONVERT(DATE, dtStart)) AS dtStartDay, SUM(value) as Sum
  FROM [DB].[table] 
 WHERE dtStart BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-30'
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, dtStart)
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, dtStart)
```

Edit: Looking at your output I have ammended the above to use `DATEPART`

Answer (score 1):

You can try running this query.

```
SELECT SUM(value) as Sum
FROM [DB].[table] 
WHERE 
CONVERT(Date,dtStart )  
    BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) 
    AND
    DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE())
```